# How to restore a docker container with a SQL server database

Tags: sql-server, docker

I'm using MacOS Sierra with the [latest version](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) of the mssql docker file for linux.

I had built a database which grew to a size of ~69 GB. I started getting an error **"Could not allocate a new page for database because of insufficient disk space in filegroup"**. I attempted to solve this problem by running this code:

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [db]
    MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'db', FILEGROWTH = 512MB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [db]
    MODIFY FILE
        (NAME = N'db_log', FILEGROWTH = 256MB )
GO
```

After doing this, I was no longer able to startup the the mssql container. I then manually replaced a backup copy of the container folder which in MacOs is called "com.docker.docker" and which contained the prior working version of the database.

After doing this, I stated getting the following error: **"The extended event engine has been disabled by startup options. Features that depend on extended events may fail to start."**

At this point I re-installed the docker container using the procedure mentioned [in this post](https://github.com/Microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/12). the command I used was:

```
docker create -v /var/opt/mssql --name mssql microsoft/mssql-server-linux /bin/true
docker run -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=Y' -e 'SA_PASSWORD=Test@123' -p 1433:1433 --volumes-from mssql -d --name sql-server microsoft/mssql-server-linux
```

Although now I'm able to start the server with the new container, I would like restore the original SQL server database (~69 GB). I tried doing so by again manually copying the file named **"Docker.qcow2"** into the docker container folder. This is obviously not working.

How can I restore my database?

Comment: If the old server won't start anymore, you can't make a backup. You need to pry out the `.mdf` and `.ldf` files of the database from the old container, transfer them to the new container and attach them (`CREATE DATABASE .. FOR ATTACH`). I'm not a Docker user, but various commands look promising (`docker container ls`, `docker cp` in particular).

Comment: do you have any suggestions as to how to pry out the .mdf and .ldf files?

Comment: My last sentence was intended to address that. I don't know the default location of SQL Server database files on Linux. On a Windows instance, it's typically `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL<majorversion>.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA`.

Comment: Using `docker inspect <container_id>` or `docker inspect <container_name>` you can find where the container has saved its files.

Comment: the problem I'm having is that the container is not starting up, therefore I'm not able to browse the directories inside the container. Ayushya, is it possible to change the startup options so that the Extended Event engine is enabled during startup?

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm having the same issues.